# I want to download MODIS data from HTTP site using Python script given in the LAADS DAAC site. But while running the script am getting error

Tags: python, http

I want to download MODIS data from HTTP site using Python script given in the LAADS DAAC site. But while running the script am getting an error:

```
error: argument -s/--source is required
```

Though I have given the source path .Following is the original script;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# script supports either python2 or python3
#
# Attempts to do HTTP Gets with urllib2(py2) urllib.requets(py3) or subprocess
# if tlsv1.1+ isn't supported by the python ssl module
#
# Will download csv or json depending on which python module is available
#

from __future__ import (division, print_function, absolute_import, unicode_literals)

import argparse
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import sys

try:
    from StringIO import StringIO   # python2
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO         # python3


################################################################################


USERAGENT = 'tis/download.py_1.0--' + sys.version.replace('\n','').replace('\r','')


def geturl(url, token=None, out=None):
    headers = { 'user-agent' : USERAGENT }
    if not token is None:
        headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
    try:
        import ssl
        CTX = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
        if sys.version_info.major == 2:
            import urllib2
            try:
                fh = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers), context=CTX)
                if out is None:
                    return fh.read()
                else:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(fh, out)
            except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                print('HTTP GET error code: %d' % e.code(), file=sys.stderr)
                print('HTTP GET error message: %s' % e.message, file=sys.stderr)
            except urllib2.URLError as e:
                print('Failed to make request: %s' % e.reason, file=sys.stderr)
            return None

        else:
            from urllib.request import urlopen, Request, URLError, HTTPError
            try:
                fh = urlopen(Request(url, headers=headers), context=CTX)
                if out is None:
                    return fh.read().decode('utf-8')
                else:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(fh, out)
            except HTTPError as e:
                print('HTTP GET error code: %d' % e.code(), file=sys.stderr)
                print('HTTP GET error message: %s' % e.message, file=sys.stderr)
            except URLError as e:
                print('Failed to make request: %s' % e.reason, file=sys.stderr)
            return None

    except AttributeError:
        # OS X Python 2 and 3 don't support tlsv1.1+ therefore... curl
        import subprocess
        try:
            args = ['curl', '--fail', '-sS', '-L', '--get', url]
            for (k,v) in headers.items():
                args.extend(['-H', ': '.join([k, v])])
            if out is None:
                # python3's subprocess.check_output returns stdout as a byte string
                result = subprocess.check_output(args)
                return result.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(result, bytes) else result
            else:
                subprocess.call(args, stdout=out)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print('curl GET error message: %' + (e.message if hasattr(e, 'message') else e.output), file=sys.stderr)
        return None



################################################################################


DESC = "This script will recursively download all files if they don't exist from a LAADS URL and stores them to the specified path"


def sync(src, dest, tok):
    '''synchronize src url with dest directory'''
    try:
        import csv
        files = [ f for f in csv.DictReader(StringIO(geturl('%s.csv' % src, tok)), skipinitialspace=True) ]
    except ImportError:
        import json
        files = json.loads(geturl(src + '.json', tok))

    # use os.path since python 2/3 both support it while pathlib is 3.4+
    for f in files:
        # currently we use filesize of 0 to indicate directory
        filesize = int(f['size'])
        path = os.path.join(dest, f['name'])
        url = src + '/' + f['name']
        if filesize == 0:
            try:
                print('creating dir:', path)
                os.mkdir(path)
                sync(src + '/' + f['name'], path, tok)
            except IOError as e:
                print("mkdir `%s': %s" % (e.filename, e.strerror), file=sys.stderr)
                sys.exit(-1)
        else:
            try:
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    print('downloading: ' , path)
                    with open(path, 'w+b') as fh:
                        geturl(url, tok, fh)
                else:
                    print('skipping: ', path)
            except IOError as e:
                print("open `%s': %s" % (e.filename, e.strerror), file=sys.stderr)
                sys.exit(-1)
    return 0


def _main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=argv[0], description=DESC)
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--source', dest='source', metavar='URL', help='Recursively download files at URL', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', dest='destination', metavar='DIR', help='Store directory structure in DIR', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--token', dest='token', metavar='TOK', help='Use app token TOK to authenticate', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
    if not os.path.exists(args.destination):
        os.makedirs(args.destination)
    return sync(args.source, args.destination, args.token)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(_main(sys.argv))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(-1)
```

I have given source, destination & token in _main function as follows

```
parser.add_argument('-s', '--source', dest='archive/orders/501235044/', metavar='https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/', help='Recursively download files at URL', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', dest='MODIS_data', metavar='D:\', help='Store directory structure in DIR', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--token', dest='token', metavar='BA52319C-4DCA-11E8-8D99-C71EAE849760', help='Use app token TOK to authenticate', required=True)
```

I got an error: `argument -s/--source is required`.

Comment: You changed the code with your data instead of giving the value as a command line argument?

Comment: I have changed in the code it self, not in the command line argument...

Comment: Then revert it and add the argument on the command line. Or use `--help`.

Comment: Hii... am very new to python.Can u please explain in detail, where to input source,destination, token for downloading data

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to deal with this is to save the script, say as `modis.py`, then in the same directory, for example:

```
python modis.py -s https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MCD19A2/2019/240/MCD19A2.A2019240.h10v04.006.2019242041719.hdf -d <destination-path/test.hdf> -t <MY-TOKEN>
```

I got this .hdf as an example from [here](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/search/order), choosing the desired product, then going through the headers at the top (TIME, LOCATION, FILES) in order to get to the .hdf file.